# What is the meaning of the words כהיום הזה in the prayer על הניסים ?

Tags: tefilla, hebrew, chanuka, translation

What is the meaning of the words כהיום הזה in the prayer על הניסים ? Are there options other than the Artscroll interpretation, "unquestionable clarity"?

Comment: It could parallel Yaakov's מכרה *כיום* את בכורתך לי

Comment: Related (and probably should be a separate question): why is this stressed regarding this particular nes? We don't say in Al Hanissim for Purim that the Jews' lives were saved כהיום הזה, or on Pesach that we were freed from Egypt כהיום הזה, etc.

Comment: Let's also compare to the last paragraph in the repetition of mussaf of rosh hashana and yom kippur where we (Ashkenaz) say כהיום הזה תביאנו ששים ושמחים...

Answer (score 2):

Es Yosef:

> Also today there is salvation and redemption, because these are these days salvation and miracles occured, therefore these days (this day) has a segula that these days of days of salvation forever.

Answer (score 1):

It means "[just] like this day".

The Tehillat HaShem Siddur translates it as:

"...and effected a great deliverance and redemption for Your people **to this very day**."

Comment: That does seem like a good literal translation, but what is the phrase meant to tell us?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I added an additional translation.

Comment: "redemption for Your people to this very day" - but the second Temple was destroyed!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok: but we're not under the domination of those who tried to force us to "forget Your Torah and violate the decrees of Your will."

Answer (score 0):

I went over the paragraph three times before my answer dawned on me.

It says "CHayom Hazeh" and then says "Achar ken"

This "Achar ken", could be referring to the entire previous statements, or it could be referring to the initial previous statement.

I think, that in this case, it is referring to the "c'Hayom Hazeh".

The battles before Chanukah, where indeed miraculous, and Hashem gave a great redemption and salvation, and performed great wonders for the small Jewish Army.

However, that "Tshuah" and "perkan" did not last very long, and it was not always clear.  The Jewish people were still divided, and needed allies for foreign nations. It was not until 10-20 years later that independence was achieved. And then, only 1 to 4 generations later, sovereignty was lost again.

However, On that day, which we celebrate as "this day", (i.e Chanukah) is when the Jewish people and leaders felt the victory of few against the many etc etc, Yeshuah and Pirkan were clear and evident to everybody, and we pray and give thanks for what "little oil" we were able to find during those times.

So in short, "k'Hayom Hazeh" means "Like this day (When the victories were apparent)", which is then contrasted with an "afterward" which focuses only on the dedication of the Beit Hamikdash and ignore the battles and hardships that came to the Jewish people aftwards during that time.